# Select rows based on date before an a column value which is not based on date

Tags: pandas

I am new to Pandas and this space in general and have a challenge where I have a dataframe like the following where I need to search on a value called 'allergies' in column 'mood', and from the resulting data, select the rows containing 'allergies', and the rows prior to this based on date. So in this example it includes the rows up to 2 day prior to 'allergies'.

My dataframe looks like:-

```
id    food     date        mood
id 1  nuts     2018-11-12  high
id 2  potatoes 2018-11-13  low
id 3  fish     2018-11-14  high
id 4  bread    2018-11-14  high
id 5  fish     2018-11-14  high
id 6  nuts     2018-11-14  high
id 7  fish     2018-11-15  allergies
id 8  beer     2018-11-16  low
id 9  bread    2018-11-17  high
id 10 fish     2018-11-18  high
id 11 pasta    2018-11-19  allergies
```

What I would like to achieve is code that will deliver something like: -

```
id    food     date        mood
id 2  potatoes 2018-11-13  low
id 3  fish     2018-11-14  high
id 4  bread    2018-11-14  high
id 5  fish     2018-11-14  high
id 6  nuts     2018-11-14  high
id 7  fish     2018-11-15  allergies
id 9  bread    2018-11-17  high
id 10 fish     2018-11-18  high
id 11 pasta    2018-11-19  allergies
```

So returning the 2 prior days 'food' entries when 'mood=allergies'.

I hope to eventually lead to an outcome where the common food item is understood to be 'fish' and this info presented back to the user such as: -

```
"Did you realize that when you eat fish you get allergies"
```

Could someone please advise me on the correct approach to this using Pandas?

Thanks

micdoher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create helper Series with compare by `allergies`, change order and use cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), then it pass to [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and for second and third column compare by `isin`:

```
s = df['mood'].eq('allergies').iloc[::-1].cumsum()
df = df[df.groupby(s).cumcount(ascending=False).isin([1,2])]
print (df)
     id      food        date  mood
1  id 2  potatoes  2018-11-13   low
2  id 3      fish  2018-11-14  high
4  id 5     bread  2018-11-16  high
5  id 6      fish  2018-11-17  high
```

**Detail**:

```
print (s)
6    1
5    1
4    1
3    2
2    2
1    2
0    2
Name: mood, dtype: int32
```

Another solution:

```
s = df['mood'].eq('allergies').iloc[::-1].cumsum().sort_index()
df = df[(df.groupby(s).cumcount(ascending=False) < 3) & s.duplicated(keep='last')]
print (df)
     id      food        date  mood
1  id 2  potatoes  2018-11-13   low
2  id 3      fish  2018-11-14  high
4  id 5     bread  2018-11-16  high
5  id 6      fish  2018-11-17  high
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this response as it does indeed deliver the answer!! One characteristic I have noticed which is understandable considering my the way I posed the question is that if 'allergies' is again included in one of the prior rows which should be returned, it the 'food' item gets ignored as I guess the selection starts again from that row. Is there any easy way to include the food item for selection even under these circumstances please?

Comment: @micdoher Unfortunately offline today, on phone only. Is possible create new question?

Comment: @jazrael I'll work through this and post the results back here as it is a good task for me in order to learn this. Thanks again for your help here!

Comment: Good news and bad news on this. I've figure out by adding a '0' to the isin part I capture the food items in rows which have allergies in them ```isin([0,1,2])]```. The bad news is I have noticed that this only 'counts' prior rows rather than including prior rows according to the date in relations to the row for which 'allergies' was detected. Is there any way to capture prior rows based within a date series from the selected rows (with 'allergies' in them?

Comment: @micdoher not sure if understand, is possible change sample data for see why `isin([0,1,2])` not working? Because seems in sample data should working nice.

Comment: @jazrael Excuse me if I have not been clear and I have changed the sample data and some wording to better explain this. We are very close with your recommended code but now need to tweak it please to select the rows prior (and inc) allergies based on date.