# targeting values in one column then using the corresponding date stamps to search other columns

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a task to solve as I try to learn Pandas and have previously posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59390818/select-rows-based-on-date-before-an-a-column-value-which-is-not-based-on-date) but now need to adapt this to search for values based on **date**, rather than counting back based on row numbers which @jazrael kindly helped me with.

Basically I have a dataframe like the following: -

```
id    food     date        mood
id 1  nuts     2018-11-12  high
id 2  potatoes 2018-11-13  low
id 4  bread    2018-11-13  high
id 5  fish     2018-11-14  high
id 6  nuts     2018-11-14  high
id 7  fish     2018-11-15  allergies
id 8  beer     2018-11-16  low
id 9  bread    2018-11-17  high
id 10 fish     2018-11-18  high
id 11 pasta    2018-11-19  allergies
```

I wish to search on column 'mood' for 'allergies', then using the 'date' value on the row where we found the value 'allergies' to count backwards 2 days and capture all the corresponding food values in the food column (whilst also inc the food items on the row allergies was detected).

So the resulting dataframe could look like the following (*I will leave the 'date' and mood' columns in for ease of understanding the question better*): -

```
id    food     date        mood
id 2  potatoes 2018-11-13  low
id 3  fish     2018-11-13  high
id 4  bread    2018-11-13  high
id 5  fish     2018-11-14  high
id 6  nuts     2018-11-14  high
id 7  fish     2018-11-15  allergies
id 9  bread    2018-11-17  high
id 10 fish     2018-11-18  high
id 11 pasta    2018-11-19  allergies
```

Any help much appreciated!

micdoher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is similar like previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59390875/2901002), only use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) for date for `allergies`, subtract `2` days and filter by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df['mood'].eq('allergies').iloc[::-1].cumsum()
df = df[df['date'].ge(df['date'].groupby(s).transform('last') - pd.Timedelta(2, unit='d'))]
print (df)
      id      food       date       mood
1   id 2  potatoes 2018-11-13        low
2   id 4     bread 2018-11-13       high
3   id 5      fish 2018-11-14       high
4   id 6      nuts 2018-11-14       high
5   id 7      fish 2018-11-15  allergies
7   id 9     bread 2018-11-17       high
8  id 10      fish 2018-11-18       high
9  id 11     pasta 2018-11-19  allergies
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['date'].groupby(s).transform('last'))
0   2018-11-15
1   2018-11-15
2   2018-11-15
3   2018-11-15
4   2018-11-15
5   2018-11-15
6   2018-11-19
7   2018-11-19
8   2018-11-19
9   2018-11-19
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: thank you very much jezrael at this seem to work well 